# I need a substitute for crushed tomatoes!

Tags: substitutions

I have tomato sauce, and I have fresh tomatoes, but I forgot to buy the 28oz can of crushed tomatoes for a sausage/pasta recipe.

Comment: Why not just use the tomato sauce in your recipe?

Comment: @moscafj Tomato Sauce usually has added sugar/salt and other ingredients that would change the final result. Substitution could work, but would require a few adjustments.

Comment: @Wolfgang I don't know that you're talking about the same kinds of tomato sauce. All of the canned "tomato sauce" doesn't really have extra ingredients. Salt, sure - but canned tomatoes already have salt, usually - but no sugar. As an example: http://www.delmonte.com/tomatoes/sauce/regular#25ebTBxCXkpaiHDY.97

Comment: Very helpful guide here: http://www.thekitchn.com/a-visual-guide-to-7-varieties-of-canned-tomatoes-223295

Comment: @Gia gives us more information. (1) What is in your tomato sauce depends on the country. (2) What is the recipe, i.e. why can't you just make a sauce from the tomatoes (like Italians do all the time).

Answer (score 7):

Cut a small cross in the ends of your whole tomatoes, dunk them in boiling water for 30 to 40 seconds and remove them. With a paring knife, grasp the edge of the skin where you cut a cross and peel the skin off.

In a large bowl, grasp the tomatoes and crush them with your hands until the size you require is achieved. You now have crushed tomatoes.

Comment: Canned crushed tomatoes usually have the consistency of blended tomatoes. OP might benefit from running them through a food processor.

Comment: Tomato concasse. Beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing both (the tomato sauce, and some fresh tomatoes) tends to yield a great result. Only fresh tomatoes can be dissappointing: The long cooked, very ripe flavor of processed tomatoes will probably be missing, especially since canned tomatoes tend to be made of tomatoes far more ripe than what is sold as fresh tomatoes.

As mentioned, fresh tomatoes can be peeled using blanching, and then crushed diced or blended; alternatively, cutting them in big chunks, peel and all, and later picking out the peels when everything has cooked off them will work.